# Overlaying an image's filename using ImageMagick (or similar)

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, filenames

I know ImageMagick's `annotate` command can superimpose some text over an image, but can it use the image's filename as this text?  I would've assumed so, but can't seem to find direct documentation that confirms this.

No doubt some combination of parameters can manage this, or is there a better way of doing this in a script?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Eric L.'s answer is correct -- +1 from me for it! -- but `-annotate` doesn't give you much control over the appearance of the text.

If you look for prettyness, then rather go for something that uses `-composite`. You can use an IM command to construct an overlay image first (which uses a semi-transparent background) and then overlay it over the original image.

Here is an example how to do it with `-composite` instead of `-annotate`, using a scripted approach that processes every PNG file in the current directory. This one even automatically adapts the font size and fits it into the available "width * 90%" -- it is a Bash script (see comments for Win equivalent):

```
for img in *.png; do

   width=$(identify -format %W ${img})
   width=$(( ${width} * 9 / 10 ))

   convert                  \
     -background '#0008'    \
     -gravity center        \
     -fill white            \
     -size ${width}x100     \
      caption:"${img}"      \
      "${img}"              \
     +swap                  \
     -gravity south         \
     -composite             \
      "with-caption-${img}"

done
```

An example illustration for one original and the respective output are below:

[image: original image] [image: image with caption]!

Here is a command that uses `-annotate`, trying to set a few things beyond the default parameters:

```
for img in so#12231624-right.png; do

   convert                   \
      "${img}"               \
     -fill red               \
     -undercolor '#0008'     \
     -pointsize 24           \
     -gravity south          \
     -annotate +0+5 "${img}" \
      "with-annotate-${img}"

done
```

[image: original image] [image: resulting image]

Comment: This is for Bash, yes. On Windows/DOS, the syntax would be something like `for %i in (*.png) do convert ....`. No final '*done*' here, and no semicolon after the `for` part.

Comment: Thank you, i actually solved it bash commandline which exists in my windows because of Git.

Comment: This worked well for me. `cd` into the image folder (all PNGs will be annotated, so make backups), then: `mogrify -gravity southwest -annotate +20+16 '%t' -font ArialUnicode -pointsize 24 -fill '#ff0000' *.png` SouthWest gives you bottom left corner placement. `+20+16` pads the text 20 pixels from the edge on the X axis, 16 pixels from the edge on the Y axis. As for fonts, [here's how to check which ones you can use, and add more](https://gothick.org.uk/2008/03/14/using-os-x-fonts-in-imagemagick/), and finally [the different ways you can specify color](https://imagemagick.org/script/color.php)

Comment: One more detail: `'%t'` and `'%f'` specify that the filename of the image should be used for the annotation text. `'%t'` will omit the file extension, while `'%f'` will include it. (On Windows these need to be escaped with an extra % like: `'%%t'`)

Answer (score 18):

It's a very old entry but I find it each time I search for this topic, and it doesn't work (for me at least). Here something that works for me:

```
convert input.jpg -gravity South -annotate 0 '%f' output.jpg
```

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: How would you specify specific characters of the filename here? Let's say I wanted the first 3 characters of the filename added on. How would I do os '%f'{0:2}?

Comment: I read that `'%f'` is for Mac and `'%%f'` is for Windows, so maybe that is why it didn't work for you at first?

Comment: [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207396/209677) is a nice alternative

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `mogrify` to add text to bunch of images at once.

```
mogrify -gravity South -annotate 0 '%f' -pointsize 24 -fill white  *.png
```

This will overwrite existing images, so make sure you have a backup before you execute this.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Steve Czetty's solution, it looks like you can set the text size and color of the annotation, using -pointsize and -fill, respectively.

Here's an example:

```
convert input.jpg -gravity south -pointsize 24 -fill yellow -annotate 0 '%f' output.jpg
```

Obviously, you can change the text size from 24 points to something else, as well the color, from 'yellow' to some other color, as per your preference.

Comment: You can also rotate the text using -annotate. Simply change 0 to 15x15 for a rotation of 15 degrees.