# imagemagick construct document with two images per A4 page

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, imagemagick

Using Ubuntu 14.04 Linux, I have a list of `.jpg` images in a folder called `Capture 01.jpg`, `Capture 02.jpg`, etc. and I would like to compose a command-line that creates a multi-page document with A4 sized pages where each page contains 2 of the images in order as given, with the name of the file as header, and with the pages containing the footer like 'Page 1 of 41'. See, e.g.:

```
------
Capture 01.jpg

[image]

Capture 02.jpg

[image]
Page 1 of 41
------
Capture 03.jpg

[image]

Capture 04.jpg

[image]
Page 2 of 41
------
...
```

The images are all the same size, roughly 1600x1200 pixels.

Knowing a bit about how ImageMagick works, I presume this will involve some sort of `collate` or `montage` command, but I am unsure how to make it fit A4 sized pages and how to format them for printing (pdf?).

Any recommendations?

EDIT: I found a question which relates to adding the file name for the image:

[Overlaying an image's filename using ImageMagick (or similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106200/overlaying-an-images-filename-using-imagemagick-or-similar)

Comment: If there is anything missing in the answers you've received, it would be nice if you could let us know. Otherwise, this issue should be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

First I would recommend not having spaces in your filenames and using enough leading zeros that the files in your directory are in alphabetic order.

I took this one image:

[image]

and duplicated it 5 more times and numbered them in sequence as:

```
lena_01.png
lena_02.png
lena_03.png
lena_04.png
lena_05.png
lena_06.png
```

and put them into a new folder called "test" on my desktop on my Mac.

Then using ImageMagick 6 with Unix bash shell scripting, I created a loop inside a subshell so that I could save the intermediate images to MIFF: format without having to save them individually. I then piped the output to a new convert to save as PDF. Note the subshell is indicated by the parenthesis surrounding the for loop.

Here is the set of commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd
cd desktop/test
arr=(`ls`)
num=${#arr[*]}
numm1=$((num-1))
numpages=`echo "scale=0; ($num+0.5)/2" | bc`
pagenum=1
(
for ((i=0; i<numm1; i=i+2)); do
  j=$((i+1))
  convert "${arr[$i]}" "${arr[$j]}" -background white -gravity center -append \
  -resize 595x842 -extent 595x842 +repage \
  -font arial -pointsize 18 -undercolor white -fill black \
  -gravity north -annotate +0+10 "${arr[$i]}" -annotate +0+431 "${arr[$j]}" \
  -gravity south -annotate +0+10 "Page $pagenum of $numpages" miff:-
  pagenum=$((pagenum+1))
  done
) | convert - ../result.pdf
```

where arr is an array of the image names in the test directory. Note that an A4 page size is 595x842 and at 72 dpi prints as 8.27 × 11.7 inches

[result.pdf](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/A4-3pages.pdf)

If you do want to keep spaces in your file names, then you can change the IFS to a new line before the arr statement and then change it back to a space afterwards. For example:

```
lena 01.png
lena 02.png
lena 03.png
lena 04.png
lena 05.png
lena 06.png
```

The code would change to the following:

```
cd
cd desktop/test
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`ls`)
num=${#arr[*]}
numm1=$((num-1))
numpages=`echo "scale=0; ($num+0.5)/2" | bc`
echo "numpages=$numpages"
pagenum=1
IFS=$OLDIFS
(
for ((i=0; i<numm1; i=i+2)); do
j=$((i+1))
convert "${arr[$i]}" "${arr[$j]}" -background white -gravity center -append \
-resize 595x842 -extent 595x842 +repage \
-font arial -pointsize 18 -undercolor white -fill black \
-gravity north -annotate +0+10 "${arr[$i]}" \
-annotate +0+431 "${arr[$j]}" \
-gravity south  -annotate +0+10 "Page $pagenum of $numpages" miff:-
pagenum=$((pagenum+1))
done
) | convert - ../result2.pdf
```

[result2.pdf](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/A4-3pages-2.pdf)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I spotted the `+repage` in the convert command, which I presume is what does the paging.

Comment: `@71906`. No, it seems to be needed to reset the virtual canvas, after the resize and event so that the text gets placed correctly relative to the gravity settings. Without it, the page numbering seemed to get placed at the bottom of the odd numbered images rather than the bottom of the even numbered images. The page size is determined by the resize 595x842, which is A4 size in pixels (at 72 dpi).

Comment: Good answer, but I have to object a little to your advice on white spaces in file names. At least in Unix, they, and a number of other characters like \*, @, [, \ etc. are permitted, and it's not hard to write scripts that deals with them correctly. In your case it would be as simple as replacing `(\`ls\`)` with `(*)`. And patterns could be done something like `(*.png)` or `pat="*.png *.jpg"; arr=($pat)`.

Comment: I agree that you can get around the spaces issue. It just makes it easier, at least for me, to avoid them. Using arr=(*) would not work, since each space separated string would be a separate element. One would have to change the IFS, which is what I would do in that case.

Comment: In the above case, it was not clear if Capture was part of the image names or the directory. I took it as to be part of the image name. But my code could be changed easily if Capture is the directory.

Comment: Hmm. Shouldn't some choice double quotes solve that issue? I didn't want to post a separate answer for such a small issue, and it's hard to explain in comments so I edited your answer to show what I mean. Please feel free to roll back if it doesn't fit, but I tested it on my end on files named on the pattern `logo\nerem *01.png`, `logo\nerem *02.png` … etc. and it works just fine.

Comment: The *.png works only because the names do not have spaces. Quotes solve the problem, but then you must do some more coding to get the names automatically from the file systems and put quotes about them. The way I would do it would be to change the IFS to $'\n' before arr=(ls). That might also work with *.png. Then change it back to IFS=" " after getting the arr. I have edited my answer above to show this method. I admit that I am not a Bash guru. So there may be other more direct methods for which I am unaware. `@ AkselA` feel free to post your full solution. I may learn something new.

Comment: Alright, I gave it a go, but I'm far from any Bash expert. I'm quite familiar with your handy IM scripts, they're far more than I've ever managed. Mostly I'm curious about your comments. I've never had to change `IFS` (except in `awk`, but that's rather different).

Answer (score 2):

On `fmw42`'s request, here is my version, which I believe is an improvement due to better handling of 'difficult' file names.

First some setup.
Create directory, download image, copy x6 and give new wacky names.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Desktop
mkdir testimagesSO
cd testimagesSO
wget "https://i.imgur.com/GeaEv21.png"

mv *.png testimage.png

Names=("Drøbaksundet\n img #1*" "Drøbaksundet\n img #2*" "Drøbaksundet\n img #3*" \
       "Drøbaksundet\n img #4*" "Drøbaksundet\n img #5*" "Drøbaksundet\n img #6*" )

echo "${#Names[@]}"

for f in "${Names[@]}"
do
  cp testimage.png "$f".png
done

rm testimage.png
```

The meat of the command is very similar to that of `fmw42`, except it's entirely array based. I also stepped around the use of `bc`.

```
arr=(*)
num=${#arr[*]}
numm1=$((num-1))
npp=2
numpages=$((($num+$npp-1)/$npp))
echo "numpages=$numpages"
pagenum=1
(
for ((i=0; i<numm1; i=i+2)); do
  j=$((i+1))
  convert "${arr[$i]}" "${arr[$j]}" -background white -gravity center -append \
  -resize 595x842 -extent 595x842 +repage \
  -font arial -pointsize 18 -undercolor white -fill black \
  -gravity north -annotate +0+10 "${arr[$i]}" \
  -annotate +0+431 "${arr[$j]}" \
  -gravity south  -annotate +0+10 "Page $pagenum of $numpages" miff:-
  pagenum+=1
done
) | convert - ../result2.pdf
```

I don't have a handy place for hosting PDFs, but this is more or less the output I get (imagine it divided over 3 A4 pages.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but your method seems to require that you set up the list of names in an array with quotes around them due to the spaces. That is an extra step that you do manually. In my method, I try to avoid doing that. Do I misunderstand? Or is your method doing that automatically from a directory that has names without quotes?

Comment: @fmw42: You mean the `Names` array in the setup part? That's just to assign names for the sake of making the example easily reproducible. `Names` is never referenced in the `convert` part, all the file names comes from the `arr` array, as it's done in your example.

Comment: I tested your code and indeed using arr=(*) gets the right number of file names even with spaces. So I guess I learned something new today. Thanks.

Comment: @fmw42: Fun! In case you're curious, I learned most of this from Gilles [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)